# Nestjs cannot resolve enum (Jest)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm using ENUM in my schema with mongodb

```
src/auth/roles/roles.enum.ts

export enum RoleEnum {
    'admin' = 1,
    'user' = 2,
  }
```

and use it in my @Prop in my schema

```
src/users/entity/users.schema.ts
import { Schema, Prop, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document} from 'mongoose';
import { RoleEnum } from 'src/auth/roles/roles.enum';
import { StatusEnum } from 'src/auth/statues/statues.enum';
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

@Schema()
export class User extends Document {
export class User extends Document {

  @Prop({    
    default: RoleEnum.user as Number,
    enum: [RoleEnum]
  })      
  roleId: number;

}
```

During the test I get this error:

> Cannot find module 'src/auth/roles/roles.enum' from
> 'users/entity/users.schema.ts'

package.json

```
"jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
```

Comment: Maybe an import issue, can you also provided imports at the beginning of users.schema.ts file ?

Comment: Thanks, can you try again using relative path ? Like `./../../../auth/roles/roles.enum`

Comment: same issue with `import { RoleEnum } from '../../../src/auth/roles/roles.enum';`

Comment: Try without `src` as a wrote

Comment: The code works. I got an error only with jest

Comment: Did the duplicate question referenced help you find a solution? Seems like `moduleNameMapper` can solve this

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ts-jest? Do you configure it in package.json ?

[setting up ts-jest for react typescript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148490/setting-up-ts-jest-for-react-typescript-project)

Comment: honestly, I'm a beginner, I have the default configuration. I updated my quesiton

Comment: I set it up with tsoa and you're using nest so I'm not sure what else might be missing :( Ensure you add --config package.json as a command line arg if you didn't already